# Plot of the derivative of a function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization, variational-calculus

I have a function `functionSL` as a function of `t` (`t<0`) where I want to find the ***extremum*** of the function and also find at which `t` it occurs. I took the derivative of `functionSL` with `t` which I wrote it as the function `functionSLD`.

```
d = 3;
torootL[a_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := a - ((2 zl Sqrt[(1 + t^2 (1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1))^-1)^-1])/((d + 1) (zl/zh)^(d + 1))) NIntegrate[(x)/Sqrt[(1 - x^2) (1 - (((1 + t^2 (1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1))^-1)^-1) (zl/zh)^-6) x^3)], {x, 0, (zl/zh)^2}]
zs[a_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := zl /. FindRoot[torootL[a, t, zl, zh], {zl, 0.5, 0, 1}]
intSL1[a_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := ((-1/(d - 1)) (zs[a, t, zh]^(2 d) (1 + t^2 (1 - (zs[a, t, zh]/zh)^(d + 1))^-1))^-1 zs[a, t, zh]^(2 d))*NIntegrate[x^d ((1 - (zs[a, t, zh]/zh)^(d + 1) x^(d + 1))/(1 - (zs[a, t, zh]^(2 d) (1 + t^2 (1 - (zs[a, t, zh]/zh)^(d + 1))^-1))^-1 (zs[a, t, zh] x)^(2 d)))^(1/2), {x, 0, 1}]
intSL2[a_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := ((-(zs[a, t, zh]/zh)^(d + 1) (d + 1))/(2 (d - 1))) * NIntegrate[x ((1 - (zs[a, t, zh]^(2 d) (1 + t^2 (1 - (zs[a, t, zh]/zh)^(d + 1))^-1))^-1 (zs[a, t, zh] x)^(2 d))/(1 - (zs[a, t, zh]/zh)^(d + 1) x^(d + 1)))^(1/2), {x, 0, 1}]
intSL3[a_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := (zs[a, t, zh]/zh)^(d + 1) * NIntegrate[x/((1 - (zs[a, t, zh]/zh)^(d + 1) x^(d + 1)) (1 - (zs[a, t, zh]^(2 d) (1 + t^2 (1 - (zs[a, t, zh]/zh)^(d + 1))^-1))^-1 (zs[a, t, zh] x)^(2 d)))^(1/2), {x, 0, 1}]
functionSL[a_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := ((-((1 - (zs[a, t, zh]^(2 d) (1 + t^2 (1 - (zs[a, t, zh]/zh)^(d + 1))^-1))^-1 zs[a, t, zh]^(2 d)) (1 - (zs[a, t, zh]/zh)^(d + 1)))^(1/2)/(d - 1)) + intSL1[a, t, zh] + intSL2[a, t, zh] + intSL3[a, t, zh] + 1)/(4 zs[a, t, zh]^(d - 1))
functionSLD[t_] := Evaluate[Derivative[0, 1, 0][functionSL][0.01, t, 1]]
```

The plot of `functionSL` is shown below,

[image: Image1]

I took some sample values of `functionSLD` for some `t`,

```
In[66]:= functionSLD[-15] // Quiet // AbsoluteTiming

Out[66]= {70.7648, 0.0477369}

In[68]:= functionSLD[-17] // Quiet // AbsoluteTiming

Out[68]= {108.509, 0.0424448}

In[69]:= functionSLD[-17.5] // Quiet // AbsoluteTiming

Out[69]= {126.48, -0.0112613}
```

From this evaluation, `functionSLD` passes the $t$ axis somewhere between -17 and -17.5.

However, by finding the root of `functionSLD`, something is off

```
In[63]:= FindRoot[functionSLD[t] == 0, {t, -17.3, -17.5, -17}] // Quiet // AbsoluteTiming

Out[63]= {1218.97, {t -> -17.}}
```

Why did `FindRoot` give a solution of `t=-17`? Clearly, from the evaluation of `functionSLD` at `t=-17` it gives `functionSLD[-17] == 0.0424448` which is not 0!

Any help?

EDIT:

I found the culprit to my problem. It has to do with how I chose the initial point in `FindRoot` in my code of `zs[a_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ]`.

If I choose the initial point as `0.5` (it could be lower) so that `FindRoot[torootL[a, t, zl, zh], {zl, 0.5, 0, 1}]`, then I get the plot,

[image: Image 2]

If I choose the initial point as `0.9` so that `FindRoot[torootL[a, t, zl, zh], {zl, 0.9, 0, 1}]`, then I get the plot,

[image: Image 3]

which is exactly what I am searching for, clearly there is a minimum around `t=-15.5`. The reason for this is I expect an extremum at around $zl=0$ (even if I choose `zl=0.5` in Mathematica somehow it still plots the correct extremum) which corresponds to `t=0` which is the first plot and at around $zl=0.9$ (I think it still works even I choose `zl=0.8` but the computed value of the other extremum is $zl=0.9$) which corresponds to `t=-15.5` which is the second plot. So the issue now becomes, how to make `FindRoot` find these two extremum points at the same plot. I do not know how to add two initial points in `FindRoot`.

Comment: Your code doesn't run, `zs[a, t, zh]` is undefined I think.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I edited the code, `zs[a, t, zh]` was in the wrong place in the code , it can now be seen.

Comment: What exactly is your question here? You said that you “want to see a plot of functionSLD[t] vs. t”. I assume that you tried to plot it? What code have you tried? What happened?

Comment: What are the definitions of `functionSLL` and `functionSLLP`?

Comment: @MarcoB I want to see the behavior of `functionSLD` vs `t`, plotting it took a very long time so I aborted it, then I tried evaluating at some sample points as I showed above. At some points there is no problem evaluating but at `t = -17` it produced an error which was hidden by the command `Quiet`, I'm not sure if doing that is correct even though it produced a value (maybe it's a wrong value?). At `t = -17.5` it just takes so long so I just aborted it again. I want to see `functionSLD` crosses the `t` axis so I am trying to see the plot too.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sorry, I have corrected the typo, it is an issue of copy pasting but I have the correct code when I ran it. There are only two functions in the code, `functionSL` which is the original function, and `functionSLD` which is the derivative of the original function.

Comment: I would suggest to simplify the problem further, e.g. `torootL` does effectively depend on `z1/zh` and `t` only, the rest can be taken out.

Comment: The integral can further be reduced to `Integrate[y/Sqrt[(1 - c y^2) (1 - y^3)] ,{y,0,1}]` with `c` depending on `z1/zh` and `t`. This can be calculated explicitly involving `HypergeometricPFQ`.

Comment: @darksun I don't understand what happened to the integral, the form is different from what I wrote.

Comment: Surely its different, its much simpler now. Your formula can be brought into this form by using substitution.

Comment: @darksun I think the substitution you used is $x^2 = y^{d+1}$ but I still cannot figure out how you removed the $t^2 (1 - (zl/zh)^{d+1} )^{-1}$ inside the square root in the denominator.

Comment: Made an edit in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider your integral in `torootL`
$$\int_0^1 \frac{zl \cdot y^d}{\sqrt{\left(1 - (zl/zh)^{d + 1} y^{d + 1}\right) \left(1 + \frac{t^2}{1 - (zl/zh)^{d + 1}} - y^{2 d}\right)}} d y.$$
It was $d=3$ and let $z=zl/zh$ such that
$$zl \cdot\int_0^1 \frac{ y^3}{\sqrt{\left(1 - z^{4} y^{4}\right) \left(1 + \frac{t^2}{1 - z^{4}} - y^{6}\right)}} d y.$$
Substitute $y^2=x$ then $d x = 2y d y$ and
$$\frac{zl}{2} \cdot\int_0^1 \frac{ x}{\sqrt{\left(1 - z^{4} x^{2}\right) \left(1 + \frac{t^2}{1 - z^{4}} - x^{3}\right)}} d x.$$
Now abbreviate $\alpha^2 = 1 + \frac{t^2}{1 - z^{4}}$ giving
$$\frac{zl}{2} \cdot\int_0^1 \frac{ x}{\sqrt{\left(1 - z^{4} x^{2}\right) \alpha^2\left(1 - (\alpha^{-2/3} x)^{3}\right)}} d x.$$
Substitute $s=\alpha^{-2/3} x$ with $d s = \alpha^{-2/3} d x$ and it follows
$$\frac{zl \alpha^{4/3}}{2 \alpha} \cdot\int_0^{\alpha^{-2/3}} \frac{ s}{\sqrt{\left(1 - z^{4} \alpha^{4/3} s^{2}\right) \left(1 - s^{3}\right)}} d s.$$
Now let $c=z^{4} \alpha^{4/3} $ such that this is proportional to
$$\int_0^{\alpha^{-2/3}} \frac{ s}{\sqrt{\left(1 - c s^{2}\right) \left(1 - s^{3}\right)}} d s,$$
where for $\alpha=1$

```
Integrate[y/Sqrt[(1 - c s^2) (1 - s^3)] ,{s,0,1}]
```

[image]

which looks like this as a function of $c$:

[image]

Note: A very good approximation to the indefinite integral is given by:

```
f[c_,q_]:=NIntegrate[x/Sqrt[(1 -  c(x^2)) (1 -  x^3)] ,{x,0,q}];
c = 0.89; 
Plot[{ Evaluate@f[c, y], 0.9/Sqrt[c](ArcSinh[Sqrt[c/(1 - c)]]-ArcSinh[Sqrt[(c (1 - y^2))/(1 - c)]])}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

**Edit 1:** `functionSL` can according to MM simplified to

```
0.25zs[a, t, zh]^(1-d) (intSL[a, t, zh] + 1-t Sqrt[1 - t^2 /(1 + t^2  -  (zs[a, t, zh]/zh)^(1 + d))]/(d+1))
```

**Edit 3:** As it looks the root finding in `zs` is the issue where finding good starting values is the heart of the problem. To do so, consider the approximation from above in simplified form

```
g[c_, y_] := ArcSinh[(Sqrt[c] (Sqrt[1 - y^2] - Sqrt[1 - c y^2]))/(-1 + c)]/Sqrt[c]
```

For the approximated `zs` it is

```
c=(((1 + t^2 (1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1))^-1)^-1) (zl/zh)^-6);
y=(zl/zh)^2;
```

Pluggin this in gives

```
d=3;
FullSimplify[a - ((2 zl Sqrt[(1 + t^2 (1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1))^-1)^-1])/((d + 1) (zl/zh)^(d + 1)))g[ (((1 + t^2 (1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1))^-1)^-1) (zl/zh)^-6),(zl/zh)^2],{z>0,z<1}]
```

The function

```
h[a_,t_,zh_]:=zl/.Quiet@FindRoot[*term from above*==0,{zl,0.5,0,1}]
```

then provides very good starting values for the original `zs`.

```
Plot[h[0.1,t,1],{t,2,20},PlotRange->Full]
```

[image]

Note: The term inside the `Arcsinh` can be simplified such that this is more or less finding a root of a large polynomial.

Comment: This is exactly the substitution I had in mind too.

Comment: @fwgb The $t$ substitution in the expression $t=\alpha^{-2/3} x$ is not the same $t$ in the expression $\alpha^2 = 1 + \frac{t^2}{1 - z^{4}}$ , right? Is this just a bad notation?

Comment: Oops. $t$ was already used. Yeah, I will rewrite it using $s$ instead. It gets even a little simpler, when we substitute to get $c$ as a factor before $s^3$.

Comment: @fwgb Also, how did you set the integration limits in the substitution $s=\alpha^{-2/3} x$? If the limits of integration of $x$ is $[0,1]$, shouldn't the limits of integration of $s$ be $[0, \alpha^{-2/3}]$?

Comment: Correct, forgot about that. Means an indefinite integral has to be used.

Comment: @fwgb So this cannot be written as a `HypergeometricPFQ` right?

Comment: Probably not, but `NIntegrate` seems to be very fast here without errors.

Comment: @fwgb I did a substitution as you recommended and it indeed made the calculation faster but instead I used $x^2 = b^{d+1} y^{d+1}$ where $b=zl/zh$ (I know you used $z=zl/zh$, but to be consistent with my notation I used $b$), the final form is similar, it is just off by a factor of $b$. However, my main question is still not yet resolved, I want to find the root of `functionSLD`. Please see my post, I edited my whole post.

Comment: See my edit. Moreover, `intSL` is the sum of 3 integrals which can all be massively simplified and maybe solved.

Comment: @fwgb I got your point, I need to find a way to write the 3 integrals in `intSL` like the first integral that is simplified in your post. However, I do not know how you got the expression `0.9/Sqrt[c](ArcSinh[Sqrt[c/(1 - c)]]-ArcSinh[Sqrt[(c (1 - y^2))/(1 - c)]])` as an approximate. That is very nice indeed!

Comment: I replaced the term $(1-s^3)$ by $const.*(1-s^2)$ which makes it an 'easy' integral.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116856/discussion-between-mathemania-and-fwgb).

Answer (score -1):

If the task is abstract it is sensible to draw improvised scetches of what to work might be. This looks very much like the integration over some profile like, [LorentzianFunction](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LorentzianFunction.html). This enters some terminology to handle such a problem.

I run the given code and found as so very ofthen that introducing:

```
MinRecursion -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 20, AccuracyGoal -> 12, \
PrecisionGoal -> 10
```

is a waste of time. OK. Your first given value profits very much, but the second already and at most the last do not.

Interpolation is not established in the scientific community for such a task. It is prefered to guess somewhat the profile and transfer the parameters to the already solved profile to do something that is a matching.

More information than solving this can be gathered on that path by methods from [ApodizationFunction](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ApodizationFunction.html). Apodization is decribed to som extent in [Apodization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apodization). The apodization is connected in this text to applications. There is in the scientific community some discussion and so [Window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) is a synonyme of some importance.

```
Plot[functionSL[0.01, t, 1], {t, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: reproduction]

There are more curves for identification in the latter source.

Apodization means forget such a plot it is full of noise and error:

```
Plot[functionSL[0.01, t, 1], {t, -17.5, -10^-6}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Plot of the far out foot apodize of the profile]

There is no visual important information in that plot. Use simpler formulas to work efficient and fast with the profile in an idealization. [Window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) shows graphically more information because such identified profile sink into noise in experiments and detectors even of the most modern generation. $-17$ is not suitalbe to gain more information. Instead use full width at half maximum or other formulaes at point that with $100 %$ probability belong to the functions graph from measurement.

Example are in this reference: [Full width at half maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_width_at_half_maximum) or in [ApodizationFunction](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ApodizationFunction.html). This article form wikipedia.org shows the principles named after the [Voigt profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voigt_profile). Some of the details are in [Faddeeva function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeeva_function). So a professional advise is fit to a pseudo-Voigt-profile and then calculate with that further.

I stopp here to avoid further confusing. The names of the variables are acronyms and might flaw my help. The dates of the page [ApodizationFunctio](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ApodizationFunction.html) show that this stuff is of high interests lately.